# rearrange a list using contents of another list in python

Tags: python, string

I have 2 lists

```
list_a = ['an378j', 'an378jijm', 'fg453h', 'fg453hbrd']

list_b = ['fg453h2564677sakjh', 'an378jijm564456464ewf', 'fg453hbrd8968764ewf', 'an378j86764edwf']
```

**Note**: The first few characters of list `list_a` are same as the first few characters of list `list_b`.

I need to rearrange List `list_b` based on the sequence, the matching characters are placed in list `list_a`.

So the new list should be:

```
['an378j86764edwf', 'an378jijm564456464ewf', 'fg453h2564677sakjh', 'fg453hbrd8968764ewf']
```

Comment: Are the elements of your lists strings?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Question is more interesting than it seems: simple `sorted(B, key=lambda el: next(i for i, v in enumerate(A) if el.startswith(v)))` wouldn't work because `an378j` is using twice, while `an378jijm` never.

Comment: Look at `filter(startswith, B)` in a comprehension over `A`.

Comment: Yes both the lists are strings. And you got it exactly right...its challenging as an378j and also fg453h is repeated twice.
m = [x for (y,x) in sorted (zip(y,x))]
this gives [fg453h2564677sakjh, , fg453hbrd8968764ewf, an378jijm564456464ewf, an378j86764edwf]
That didn't help a lot.

Comment: @Brad. Please fix your question to indicate strings. Right now you have variable names or just invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very verbose, but it does what you want.

```
list_a = ['an378j', 'an378jijm', 'fg453h', 'fg453hbrd']
list_b = ['fg453h2564677sakjh', 'an378jijm564456464ewf', 'fg453hbrd8968764ewf', 'an378j86764edwf']

sorted_b = []
grouped_b = {}
for item_a in list_a:
    for item_b in list_b:
        if item_b.startswith(item_a):
            if item_a not in grouped_b:
                grouped_b[item_a] = [item_b]
            else:
                grouped_b[item_a].append(item_b)

    for item in sorted(grouped_b[item_a]):
        if item not in sorted_b:
            sorted_b.append(item)

print sorted_b
```

> ['an378j86764edwf', 'an378jijm564456464ewf', 'fg453h2564677sakjh',
>   'fg453hbrd8968764ewf']

Comment: Your solution wouldn't work for this data: `A = ['an378j', 'an378jijm', 'fg453h', 'fg453hbrd', 'an']`; `B = ['fg453h2564677sakjh', 'an378jijm564456464ewf', 'fg453hbrd8968764ewf', 'an378j86764edwf', 'an378j']`; Output: `['an378j', 'an378j86764edwf', 'an378jijm564456464ewf', 'fg453h2564677sakjh', 'fg453hbrd8968764ewf']` - look at last elem.

Comment: Thank you all. The solutions given are working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
A = ['an378j', 'an378jijm', 'fg453h', 'fg453hbrd']

B = ['fg453h2564677sakjh', 'an378jijm564456464ewf', 'fg453hbrd8968764ewf', 'an378j86764edwf']

tmp_A = A.copy()

def get_pair(b_val):
    # All possible pairs from A for b_el:
    possible_pairs = [val for i, val in enumerate(tmp_A) if b_val.startswith(val)]
    # Longest of possible pairs is pair we should use:
    pair = sorted(possible_pairs, key=len, reverse=True)[0]
    # Pair we use can't be used again:
    tmp_A.pop(tmp_A.index(pair))
    # Return:
    return pair

# Index of pair is key to sort:
res = sorted(B, key=lambda b_val: A.index(get_pair(b_val)))
print(res)
# ['an378j86764edwf', 'an378jijm564456464ewf', 'fg453h2564677sakjh', 'fg453hbrd8968764ewf']
```

For different input:

```
A = ['an378j', 'an378jijm', 'fg453h', 'fg453hbrd', 'an']

B = ['fg453h2564677sakjh', 'an378jijm564456464ewf', 'fg453hbrd8968764ewf', 'an378j86764edwf', 'an378j']

# ['an378j86764edwf', 'an378jijm564456464ewf', 'fg453h2564677sakjh', 'fg453hbrd8968764ewf', 'an378j']
```